# Linux qt application after deployment - symbol lookup error: libQt5Core.so.5 undfined symbol: uncv_getDefaultName_56

Tags: c++, linux, qt, centos

I want to deploy my qt application on Linux but I get linking error like this:

> symbol lookup error libQt5Core.so.5 undefined symbol: uncv_getDefaultName_56

It might have something in common with libicu but it's in the /lib64 directory in proper version. My goal is to deploy everything statically and I'm not sure if it's even possible with QT

Comment: On a side note, be careful when linking statically with certain libraries, like `Qt`. The license differs often on what you can and cannot do when linking statically or dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ldd on your binary to find out which libraries it needs.

Unless you have a commercial license for Qt, you can only deploy dynamically linked binaries. You can deploy the required dynamic libraries which should be installed on your system. On my system I find the following for libQt5Core

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Dec 26 19:30 /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so -> 
libQt5Core.so.5.12.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Dec 26 19:30 /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 -> 
libQt5Core.so.5.12.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Dec 26 19:30 /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5.12 -> 
libQt5Core.so.5.12.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5421416 Dec 26 19:32 /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5.12.0
```

libQt5Core.so.5.12.0 is the actual library.  The others are links created by ldconfig. You should include them all with your binary.

Alternatively, you can install the libQt5 package(s) on your target system.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. Everything is found and I have built qt statically. The problem in my opinion is with the libicui18n.so.56 library which also linked. In fact I can resolve by adding this library to my deploy directory but then I cannot show Qtray icon from application.

Comment: All .so (shared object) files follow the same rules. Try copying all the libicui18n.so* files from your lib folder to your deployment folder.  I suspect the one you did copy was just a dynamic link which now points to nothing.

Comment: I've tried all of these things and none of them work correctly. My conclusion is that, that you need to have installed qtbase package to run application with Qttrayicons on Linux. If anyone, ever would find solution I will be glad to know it.